# side_effect for "sys.argv" returns a tuple of 1,1 regardless of what I set it to when doing mock.patch

Tags: python, python-unittest

For some reason side_effect isn't having an effect when I try to change the first two instances of sys.argv to be anything they just default to 1,1.

```
"""testing"""
def check_arg():
try:
    num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
    num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
except IndexError:
    return False, False
except ValueError:
    return False, False
else:
    if num1 < num2:
        return num1, num2
  #  elif num1 == num2:
  #     return False, False
    else:
        return num2, num1       


  """test"""
  @mock.patch("sys.argv", side_effect=["9", "2"])
  def test_check_arg(self, mocktest):
    checkarg = check_arg()
    self.assertEqual(checkarg, (2, 2))
```

"""

Problem:
...
, line 23, in test_check_arg
self.assertEqual(checkarg, (2, 2))
AssertionError: Tuples differ: (1, 1) != (2, 2)

First differing element 0:
False
2

- (1,1)

- (2, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `side_effect` is not what you need in this case. It's enough if you use:

```py
"""testing"""
def check_arg():
try:
    num1 = int(sys.argv[0])
    num2 = int(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    return False, False
except ValueError:
    return False, False
else:
    if num1 < num2:
        return num1, num2
  #  elif num1 == num2:
  #     return False, False
    else:
        return num2, num1       


  """test"""
  @mock.patch("sys.argv", ["9", "2"])
  def test_check_arg(self):
    checkarg = check_arg()
    self.assertEqual(checkarg, (2, 9))
```

This should work fine. But reading the docs about `sys.argv` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) `sys.argv[0]` always contains the name of the script so it will probably be better like:

It seems that `side_effect` is not what you need in this case. It's enough if you use:

```py
"""testing"""
def check_arg():
try:
    num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
    num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
except IndexError:
    return False, False
except ValueError:
    return False, False
else:
    if num1 < num2:
        return num1, num2
  #  elif num1 == num2:
  #     return False, False
    else:
        return num2, num1       


  """test"""
  @mock.patch("sys.argv", ["test_argv.py", "9", "2"])
  def test_check_arg(self):
    checkarg = check_arg()
    self.assertEqual(checkarg, (2, 9))
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but yes its intended to get the 2nd and 3rd items. The way sideffect works is that it should return 9, 2 whenever sys.argv is being called but its only returning 1.

Comment: I initially thought it was just a matter of an `ImportError`. I checked it and now it should work fine!

Comment: Nice! Thanks it worked! But why didn't we need to have side effect in this case? For instance when I had a similar scenario with Input it needed side effect every time it was called. Is it because sys.argv is considered one instant and so side effect only deals with multiple instances?

Comment: Cool! So from what I read, `side_effect` needs to be a function, iterable or exception. In your case it was an iterable (a `list` is an example of iterable in Python) so every time `mock` is called it will return the next element in the iterable (in the first call, it resulted in `sys.argv = "9"` and in the second call `sys.argv = "2"`). If you need further understanding/examples here you will find more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect 

Also it would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted! Thank you!

Comment: So there is a difference between patching sys.argv and using sys.arg[1] and sys.argv[2]?

Comment: The key is in `side_effect`. Without it we just set the value for `sys.argv = ['test_argv.py', '9', '2']`. With side effect, `sys.argv` becomes a `MagicMock` object `<MagicMock name='argv' id='139658098588624'>` (using `sys.argv[1] or [2]` here won't serve our purposes). Also you can see that by calling `sys.argv.side_effect` we get a `<list_iterator object at 0x7f04af5c0e10>`. Another way to pass the original test would be to use

```
`num1 = int(sys.argv.side_effect.__next__())`
`num2 = int(sys.argv.side_effect.__next__())`
to iterate over the elements, but it's unintuitive.